# any open-source tool or excel macro to extract a list of xpaths from an xml?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

Basically I want to be able to specify an xml or 2 like so (would be great if you could select a folder and it would grab all the xml files from there):

Xml 1:

```
<Client>
              <LastName>Bill</LastName>
              <FirstName>Gates</FirstName>
              <MiddleName/>
              <Suffix/>
              <DateOfBirth>30-May-1968</DateOfBirth>
              <PlaceOfBirth/>
              <SSN>n/a</SSN>
              <Gender>Male</Gender>
              <District>
                <City>SHELTON</City>
                <Mayor>wong</Mayor>
              </District>
              <State>WA</State>
              <Zip>96484</Zip>
</Client>
```

Xml 2:

```
<Client>
              <LastName>Warron</LastName>
              <FirstName>Buffet</FirstName>
              <MiddleName>P</MiddleName>
              <Suffix/>
              <DateOfBirth>12-Aug-1957</DateOfBirth>
              <PlaceOfBirth>Mississippi</PlaceOfBirth>
              <SSN>n/a</SSN>
              <Gender>Male</Gender>
              <City>Missi</City>
              <State>KS</State>
              <Account>
                <Type>
                <Name>Cash</Name>
                <Currency>USD</Currency>
                <Country>USA</Country>
                </Type>
              </Account>
              <Zip>66096</Zip>
</Client>
```

Then put a list of xpaths in column A of an excel sheet (ie. 'Xpaths') such as:

```
/Client/DateOfBirth
/Client/Account/Type/Name
/Client/Zip
/Client/District/City
```

Desired behavior: Receive results in a table of a new excel sheet (ie. 'Results') with columns such as:

```
/Client/DateOfBirth  /Client/Account/Type/Name   /Client/Zip   /Client/District/City

----------------     ------------------------    ------------   --------------------
30-May-1968                                      96484              SHELTON
12-Aug-1957           Cash                       66096
```

Wouldn't mind if this was done using excel vba macro.

UPDATE - debugging Tim's answer:
[image]

Comment: You can use xpath with an instance of msxml, and use Dir() to loop though all the XML files in a folder.  Your sample XML has no root element, so that might cause a problem if that' the whole content.

Comment: You ask a lot. Do you have any code written so far? As Tim mentioned, there's no root element, so the file won't parse properly.

Comment: They are actually 2 xmls with Client being the root element

Comment: This question is severely underspecified. You only show *one* XML document (malformed at that). Please provide at least two XML documents and what the result must be, Now one has to guess...

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev  - see edit.

Comment: Anyone willing to add more for the bounty, accepted answer and upvote?

Comment: That screenshot is illegible... I'd love a bounty etc., but Tim William's answer actually works fine.

Comment: You can zoom in on the screenshot. I'm not going to waste the bounty so I will give to Tim (most useful answer so far) before it expires unless someone else posts something that works for me. BTW, does anyone know of any tools (non vba) that could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me using your examples (with the xml DTD added at the top)...

```
Sub Tester()
    ProcessFiles ThisWorkbook.Path, Sheet1.Range("A1:D1")
End Sub

Sub ProcessFiles(FolderPath As String, XPathRange As Range)
    Dim oXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim fName As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rv

    x = 1
    fName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While fName <> ""
        Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
        oXML.Load FolderPath & "\" & fName

        For Each c In XPathRange.Cells
            rv = ""
            Set oNode = oXML.SelectSingleNode(c.Value)
            If Not oNode Is Nothing Then
                rv = oNode.nodeTypedValue
            End If
            c.Offset(x, 0).Value = rv
        Next c

        x = x + 1
        fName = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the screenshot I posted in the question - It doesn't seem to be finding the xml file as Msgbox "entry" never got executed when I run the Tester Sub. Then I tried manually doing oXML.Load "C:\xpathtest2\t1.xml" I received this error: "Automation error unspecified error"

Comment: Did you add a reference to MSXML in your project?  I tested with both v4 and v6.  If that's set, there may be a problem with your XML files.

Comment: Or maybe try turning off Norton AV.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add a Xml Map to your Workbook and pull the desired elements to your sheet:

1. Open your Xml source file wiith Excel
2. Select "Use the Xml Source task pane" option and click "OK"
3. Accept that Excel will create a schema for you
4. Drag the desired elements from the Xml Source pane to columns
5. Right-click on any column and select "Xml" -> "Import"
6. Open the desired Xml file.

Comment: too fiddly - i need to be able to just click a button and return only the xpaths I specified.

Comment: You can prepare a workbook with all the steps 1-5 and record a macro to perform steps 5+6 on button click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675260(VS.85).aspx

To transfer xml to column use

```
            If adoRS.Fields(ndx).Type = adChapter Then
                'you have a new column
                Set adoChildRS = adoRS.Fields(ndx).Value
                WalkHier iLevel, adoChildRS
            Else
                'put value in column
                Debug.Print iLevel & ": adoRS.Fields(" & ndx & _
                   ") = " & adoRS.Fields(ndx).Name & " = " & _
                   adoRS.Fields(ndx).Value
            End If
```

Comment: good start - 1. Need some way of capturing the whole xpath not just the child tag. 2. provide the loop to write to the worksheet. 3. provide a facility to OpenFileDialog where you can add 1 or more xmls. If you do 2 out of the 3 the bounty, accepted answer and upvote is yours.